# What is this Burmese/Myanmmarese Brown to Black dried tea leafs?

Tags: asian-cuisine, burmese-cuisine

While in Phra Khanong market, the only Burmese market I know of in Bangkok, I bought the following seemingly-to-me similar products: brown to black dried tea leaves (pictured below).

I drank a small glass of hot tea made from these leaves, and it had a very mild and comforting taste.

What is this Burmese/Myanmmarese brown-to-black dried tea leaf? br/>
What is the English name, please?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, I think it's black tea leafs, dried; after drinking 3 cups I feel very "excited" from nothing; like other caffeine boosts I had in the past.

Comment: Definitely - I stayed awake about 48 hours. That was terrible !

Answer (score 2):

These could be leaves to make "Lahpet" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahpet), so perhaps you can drink them too?

Answer (score 1):

Google Lens can't parse the first "bell" bag, but for the second, here's what it thinks:

နတ်ဩတ (*naat aut*), "Miracle"

၍ ရှေးရက်သစ်ရွက်နု (*shayy raat saitrwatnu*), "Ancient fresh leaves"

အကောင်းဆုံးလက်ဖက် (*aakaunggsonelaathpaat*), "The best tea"

So it looks like you've got some "Miracle" brand tea there, which if the marketing is to be believed is ancient, fresh *and* the best.  Clearly you made a good choice!

Slightly more seriously, the last word there, လက်ဖက်, is usually rendered *[lahpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lahpet)* in English and refers to the fermented tea leaves used to make Burma's national dish *lahpet thoke*, tea leaf salad.  So if you pick up *lahpet* from any Burmese grocery, it will taste quite similar -- although it may sadly not be *the* best.